# using html5 data-action and angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I was using jquery ealier before starting to use angularjs.

Earlier I head this:-

```
$('[data-action^="backtop"]').click(function(){

});
```

and now after integrating angular this does not work on click.

Is there a way i can correct without having to change everything to directives.

Comment: Found a solution, using  jQuery's event delegation. So i will be doing `$(document).on('click','[data-action=^="backdrop"]',function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

Where you'd put a `data-action` and then a selector over it that fires a handler - use a [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).

In the template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl"> <!-- or whatever container --> 
 <button ng-click="ctrl.backtop()" ng-init="count=0">
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
class MyCtrl {
    backtop() {
       // code here, what you had in the click handler
    }
}
app.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);
```

Or in ES5 syntax:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function(){ 
    this.backtop = function() { /* handler code here */ }
});
```

Comment: Nice Solution,  but i cannot actually do that as i will have to migrate too many things to make them work again. I have loads of such selectors.

Comment: I want to use angular now as i have much more implementations to do and i will be migrating to angular soon, but for the time being i just needed a quick solution.

Comment: Then you might as well not use Angular, you can't use selectors as the event handlers won't be aware of Angular's change tracking - you'll have lots of confusing bugs - it won't be worth it